# Laravel Verify Authenticated user on a different machine

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel app which calls a api service [owned by me, on a different machine - also Laravel based] how can the API service verify that the incoming request was made by a logged user?

Comment: Research about Authentication with API and JWT Tokens. This is too broad.

Comment: What does a different machine means? Different domain? If the domain is the same you can store session to cookie otherwise use JWT as already recommended.

Comment: different domain + machine, its mysite.com accessing api.mysite.com